# Catkin overlay tutorial

Tags: ros, catkin, rosws, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

When I try "wstool init" in section 3.2 i get the following error :

```
$ wstool init
ERROR: Cannot find required rosinstall library version, check your installation (also of vcstools) is up-to-date. One frequent cause is that rosinstall 0.5 is still installed in /usr/local/lib.
cannot import name __MULTIPRO_CMD_ALIASES__

$ rosinstall --version
rosinstall 0.6.25
vcstools:  0.1.29
SVN:       svn, version 1.7.5 (r1336830); 
Mercurial: Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.2.2); 
Git:       1.7.10.4; 'reset --keep': True, submodules: True
Tar:       tarfile version: $Revision: 85213 $; 
Bzr:       Bazaar (bzr) 2.6b2; 

$ which rosinstall
/usr/local/bin/rosinstall
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58167/catkin-overlay-tutorial/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-14**:
Can you check `rosinstall --version` and `which rosinstall`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This answer covers this problem and details how to solve it:

http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu/?answer=49153#post-id-49153

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1